# How to create a DotNetNuke skin in Visual Studio

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm looking for tutorials on how to develop a skin for dnn 7+ using visual studio 2012. The only thing google is finding for me is paid tutorials. Can anyone reference a **free** tut or two that walks through the process of creating a skin for dnn 7+ using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't many/any available. I have it on my list of things to do, but that list is rather long these days.

Here's how I would start.

1) Download the SOURCE package of my free MultiFunction skin https://multifunction.codeplex.com/

2) Install the SOURCE package via the HOST/Extensions page of your DNN development environment.

3) Open up the SLN file in /portals/_default/skins/multifunction

4) Make changes.

5) Build in RELEASE mode to get a new ZIP file created (I think it goes into /packages in that skins/multifunction folder, though I Might have updated to use /install instead).

FYI: Every time you Build in debug mode, the project will copy the files in the Containers folder to /portals/_default/containers/multifunction

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris. There is no sln in /portals/_default/skins/multifunction, only user controls, xml files and their assets.

Comment: Download the SOURCE package from Codeplex, not the INSTALL package.

Comment: When trying to open the solution the main project doesn't load and gives the error "The imported project "c:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."

Comment: I commented out the `<input>` element that's being referenced and that worked. Not sure if that will cause problems down the road though?

Comment: @bflemi3 you'll want to download MSBuild Community Tasks (or run Nuget for it) if you want the automated packaging features to work